# Retrieve a single entry from app-engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to retrieve a single entry from my mobile backend starter project (https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference) built on app-engine.

I know the ID of the entity that I want but can't figure out why my code is giving a nullpointerexception

```
if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("rideId")){
        updateRide = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("rideId");
        Log.e(TAG, updateRide);

        CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity> handler = new CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(final CloudEntity result) {
                // do something helpful
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(final IOException exception) {
                handleEndpointException(exception);
            }
        };

        newPost.setId(updateRide);
        mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend().get(newPost, handler);  // this line gives the exception
    }
```

I have confirmed that the intent bundle is sending the correct ID string

Comment: Your `mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend()` returns null. It's impossible to say why from this code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't initiated it yet - I had refactored my code and move the implementation before the initiation. Can I ask how you could tell that `mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend()` was null and the problem wasnt that it wasn't returning a result as I had thought

Comment: If a result was null, this line would not throw an exception. An exception is thrown when you try to call a method on a null object, like in your case: `null.get(newPost, handler)`.